# Sum of the powers

Tags: math

I have to code to evaluate the value of following sequence :

`( pow(1,k) + pow(2,k) + ... + pow(n,k) ) % MOD`
for given value of n,k and MOD.

I have tried searching it on [internet](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%29=f%28n-1%29%2bn%5Ek&dataset=). I got an equation [image]. It contains zeta functions and it seems difficult in implementation. I want any simple approach for implementing the same. Note that the value of n is large, so that we cannot simply use brute force to pass the time limit.

Comment: What does 'large' mean?  Can you give some example values for `n`, `k` and `MOD`?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mark : lets say that the maximum values of n, k and MOD can be 10^9, i.e. 1000000000 .

Comment: Why do you need to evaluate this?

Comment: @lhf : This is the sub problem of the problem which I need to solve.

Answer (score 1):

[Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) might be of help. Calculate the coefficients of the polynomial with 1..n as roots. That pretty trivial. Then use the identities.

It's just the first thing that comes to mind when I see sums of powers.

I think it is nicely compatible with modular arithmetics - there are only multiplications and additions.

I must admit, that Newton's identities are only the rearrangement of the terms, so not much speed gain here.

Answer (score 1):

JUST USE PYTHON

```
k=input("Enter value for K: ")
n=input("Enter value for N: ")
mod=input("Enter value for MOD: ")
sum=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    sum+=pow(i,k)
result=sum % mod
print mod
```

May be this code is gonna help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that math.stackexchange.com is a better bet.

But here are random facts that, depending on parameters, may make the problem more manageable.

First, factor `MOD`, solve for each prime power factor, then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find the answer for `MOD`.  Thus without loss of generality, you may assume that MOD is a prime power.

Next, note that `1^k + ... + MOD^k` is always divisible by `MOD`.  Therefore you can replace `n` by `n mod MOD`.

Next, if `MOD = p^i` and `j` is not divisible by `p`, then `j^((p-1) * p^(i-1))` is `1` mod `MOD`, so we can reduce the size of `k`.

Of course if `(k, n) < MOD` and `MOD` is prime, this will not help you at all.  (Which, depending on how this problem arises, may well be the case.)

(If `k` is small enough, there are explicit formulas that you can produce for the sum.  But it seems that for you `k` can be large enough to make that approach intractable.)